# rails-breadcrumb and I18n localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, breadcrumbs

I'm using [BreadcrumbsOnRails](https://github.com/weppos/breadcrumbs_on_rails) in my application.
Application is fully localized, but I have one problem with navigation translating.
When menu is rendered, the localized name is always on russian (an even I18n.locale='en')

set up locale in **application controller**:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_locale

  add_breadcrumb I18n.t('navigation.home'), :root_path
  ...
  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || session[:lang]
    session[:lang] = locale unless session[:lang] == locale
    I18n.locale = locale
  end
  ... 
end
```

I have next **controller** with breadcrumb:

```
class ExamsController < ApplicationController
  ...
  add_breadcrumb I18n.t('navigation.exams'), :exams_path
  before_filter :exam_breadcrumb, :only => [:show, :edit]
  ...
end
```

[#config/lib/breadcrumbs_builder](https://gist.github.com/MicRum/8350799)

haml **view** with breadcrumbs:

```
- breadcrumbs = render_breadcrumbs(:separator => ' / ', :tag => :li, :builder =>       BreadcrumbsBuilder)
 - unless breadcrumbs.blank?
   .subnav#main-subnav
     .container
       %ul.breadcrumbs
          = breadcrumbs
```

With this hardcode everything is OK:

```
add_breadcrumb I18n::t('navigation.exams', locale: 'en'), :exams_path
```

Answer (score 1):

Had to add breadcrumbs in separate method. Other solution I have not found...

```
class ExamsController < ApplicationController

   before_filter :exam_breadcrumb_translate
   before_filter :exam_breadcrumb, :only => [:show, :edit]
   ...

   private

   def exam_breadcrumb_translate
     add_breadcrumb I18n::t('navigation.exams'), :exams_path
   end

   def exam_breadcrumb
     @exam = Exam.find(params[:id])
     add_breadcrumb @exam.name, exam_questions_path(@exam)
   end
```